# display next view controller in stroboard

Tags: ios7, storyboard, xcode5, viewcontroller

i am new to ios development
i have created a slash screen that check internet connection when application load and that is my rootviewcontroller.
i have created a next view using uiviewcontroller in same storyboard name Main_iphone
the storyboard id of viewcontroller is "HomeScreen".

the question is how do i jump on "Homescreen" from "SplashScreen" when internet connection found

I had created the function to jump on next screen-

```
[self perform:@selector(goToNextView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
-(void) goToNextView{
   UIStroyboard *iphone=[UIStoryBoardWithName:@"Main_iphone" bundel: nil];
}
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

-(void) goToNextView{

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"HomeScreen" sender:self];
```

}

If, you want to set some value use this :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"HomeScreen"]) 
    {
            // do here
    }
}
```